# ¿Como insertar una tabla intermedia en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

teniendo las siguientes tablas-migraciones en laravel:

**Tabla persona**

```
Schema::create('personas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string("nombre");
    $table->string("apellidom")->nullable();
    $table->string("apellidop")->nullable();
    $table->date("fecha_nacimiento")->nullable();
    $table->string("ci")->nullable();
    $table->enum("sexo",["masculino","femenino"])->defautl("masculino");
    $table->string("celular")->nullable();
    $table->string("direccion")->nullable();
    $table->enum("tipo",["trabajador","paciente"])->default("trabajador");
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Tabla Cargos**

```
Schema::create('cargos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string("nombre");
    $table->text("descripcion")->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Tabla intermedia apersona-cargos**:

```
Schema::create('persona_cargo', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer("persona_id");
    $table->integer("cargo_id");
    $table->date("fecha");
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Siendo la relación de muchos a muchos entre **Persona** y **Cargos**.

```
$persona=new Persona($request->all());
$persona->save();
$cargo=new Cargo($request->all());
$cargo->save();
//aqui cual seria el codigo siguiente?
```

> Como inserto la tabla intermedia persona_cargo?, ya que este no cuenta con un modelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para insertar en la tabla intermedia basta con llamar al método de la relación y a continuación acceder al método `attach()`:

```
$persona->cargos()->attach($cargo->id);
```

También le puedes enviar un array de ids:

```
$persona->cargos()->attach([1, 2, 3]);
```

Si tu tabla intermedia cuenta con columnas adicionales a las llaves foráneas, puedes insertar de esta forma:

```
$persona->cargos()->attach($cargo->id, ['expira' => $expiracion]);
```

Para sincronizar los registros relacionados puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$persona->cargos()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

Cualquier id que no se encuentre en ese array, será eliminado de la tabla intermedia que corresponda a la relación, siendo así, sólo quedarían relacionados los cargos con ids: 1, 2 y 3.

Comment: ya lo había conseguido, y si es la forma correcta.